# What does the word "respectively" mean in software development?

Tags: meaning

> C# Textreader and TextWriter are the another way to read and write file **respectively**...
>   
>   I added a text box and button I called tbUpdate and btUpdate **respectively**...
>   
>   In the right hand column, we’ll use three TextBlocks; the first and third as fixed labels (with the values Likeability: and % **respectively**)...
>   
>   WorkerSupportsProgress and WorkerSupportsCancellation which hold true/false values that let the backgroundworker report progress or cancel an async progress **respectively**...

While learning many the many different aspects of development, I have not come across a book or series where the word **respectively** is not used in explaining an example. Honestly I guess it's implied that we know what it means. To me I always kind of skim over it because I can usually figure out what they're saying through the surrounding context. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: This is really a question about the English language, not so much about programming.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is not really a programming question. It is always true in English that when you say "A and B are true for X and Y respectively," you mean that A is true for X and B is true for Y.

So to take your examples

> C# Textreader is another way to read a
>   file and TextWriter is another way to
>   write a file...
>
> I added a text box I called tbUpdate and
>   button I called btUpdate...
>
> In the right hand column, we’ll use three TextBlocks;
>   the first (with the value Likeability) and third (with
>   the value %) as fixed labels...
>
> WorkerSupportsProgress which holds true/false values that
>   lets the backgroundworker report progress and
>   WorkerSupportsCancellation which holds true/false values
>   that let the backgroundworker cancel an async progress...

Comment: ie. respectively = "in that order" in this context

Answer (score 5):

"Respectively" is used when presenting two lists that have a direct correlation.

Those sentences can be rewritten like so:

> C# Textreader, to read, and TextWriter, to write, are another way...
>
> OR:
>
> C# provides another way to read, with TextReader, and to write, with TextWriter, ...

Each item in both lists has a direct relation with respect to the corresponding item in the other list.

Answer (score 2):

> I added a text box and button I called
>   tbUpdate and btUpdate respectively...

means

> I added a text box I called tbUpdate, and a button I called btUpdate ...

Just an addition, my guidebook prefer the latter form because it's easier to read (imagine if there are 5 items being listed).