# Use of "respectively" twice

Tags: word-usage, writing-style

Is it correct to use respectively in this way in a written text?

> The first month of Spring (respectively Summer) is March (respectively June).

Could you please point to some examples where it is used.

Comment: Related: [What does the word “respectively” mean in software development?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24525/), [Is this correct use of 'respectively'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197570/), and [Using “respectively” with “and” vs. “or”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/175657/). But I think it's General Reference that the examples here are not valid English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I disagree that this is GR. _Respectively_ is quite a difficult word to pinpoint, and the dictionaries I’ve looked in (even the OED) give overly brief, undetailed descriptions/examples. I definitely think the way it is used here is uncommon and quirky, but it’s perfectly understandable and straightforward, and I can’t think of a different way of phrasing it without losing some of the nuance of meaning. In at least some other languages, the word _respectively_ (in its local form) is used more or less the same as in English, but the usage given here would also be perfectly fine.

Comment: @Janus: **respectively** - [*Separately or individually and **in the order already mentioned** (used when enumerating two or more items or facts that refer back to a previous statement*)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/respectively). That looks pretty straightforward to me. If you think OP's usage has any credibility at all, I can only say I don't, and structurally it borders on nonsense to me. Standard usage here is *The first months of Spring and Summer are March and June respectively*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Using _respectively_ when enumerating two or more items is exactly what eev2’s example does—the only trouble is that it does it with both the ‘beginning’ statement and the statement that refers back to the ‘beginning’ statement. This is valid in other languages, but not in English; but the definitions and usage examples in dictionaries are far from clear about this. In fact, the definition you quote is downright inaccurate, since it would also license such uses as, “John went to Greece and Spain, respectively”, which is nonsense.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's not obvious that repeating respectively is not valid. There are analogous patterns where you -do- repeat, but logically isn't necessary. 'The X-er ..., the Y-er' - eg 'The longer you wait, the more frustrated you get'. "Is it correct to use 'the' twice like that?" Of course it is, to us.

Comment: @Janus: That definition seems fine to me. I think you're ignoring the words I specifically highlighted *(in the order already mentioned)*. OP's example (and your *John - Greece - Spain* one) incorrectly use the word ***before having previously mentioned anything in any particular order that can be referred back to***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, that was rather my point. In “John went to Greece and Spain, respectively”, _respectively_ **does** refer back to two or more items in the particular order already mentioned: Greece first, then Spain, both mentioned just before _respectively_. Greece and Spain don’t really ‘refer back’ to any previous statement in **any** use of _respectively_, which is why the dictionary definition is quite bad and requires that you already know how to use the word in order to see what is and is not proper use of it.

Comment: @Janus: I think your perspective there must somehow derive from how *other* languages might use similar adverbial qualifiers. The way ***respectively*** works in English seems unremarkable and unambiguous to me. And ELU is not a suitable site for non-native speakers wishing to *learn* standard English. I remain convinced this is an ELL-level question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The example you give is perfectly clear and understandable, but I very much doubt any native speaker of English would ever use *respectively* in that manner. Therefore, I think it’s fair to say that it is at least *unidiomatic*, if perhaps not quite ungrammatical.

The way you’ve used *respectively* here is very similar to how, for example, German can use *beziehungsweise (bzw.)*, but the similarities between *respectively* and *beziehungsweise* do not include this usage.

In English, when two things are being compared in a ‘parallel’ manner like this, *respectively* is only used **once** in total: either after both parallel pairs, or before the latter half of each pair.

To clarify and expand a little, let’s say we have these four pairings:

> **Seasons** — **Months**
> Spring — March
> Summer — June
> Autumn — September
> Winter — December

Imagine the pairs as a spreadsheet or as tabular data. The rows represent the connection between seasons and months, while the columns represent seasons and months individually. The simplest, default way of summing up the relationship between the columns using words would be one row at a time: “The first month of spring is March; the first month of summer is June”, etc.

*Respectively* can be used to sum up several rows at once. When doing so in English, first list all the entries in the *Seasons* column as a simple list (“A, B, C, and D”); then list all the entries in the *Months* column in the same manner, adding *respectively* either before or after this entire list.

Unlike some other languages, *respectively* is not used when listing the *Seasons* column, only the *Months* column; and it also cannot intervene between the individual items in the list.

In other words, the standard way to say what you’re trying to say is either of:

> The first month of spring, summer, autumn, and winter is March, June, September, and December, respectively.
>
> The first month of spring, summer, autumn, and winter is, respectively, March, June, September, and December.

(Whether you write “the first month of … is” or “the first months of … are” doesn’t really matter; both are fine.)

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate response. At least in mathematical papers I have seen people writing "The function f(x) tends to 0 (1) as x tends to 0 (1)" which is short for saying "f(x) tends to 0 as x tends to 0 and f(x) tends to 1 as x tends to 1".

Comment: This is a great answer, but I'm queasy about the parenthetical.  To my ear, only "The first month**s** of spring and summer **are** March and June (respectively)" is correct.

Comment: @ChrisSunami The plural is probably what I’d say naturally myself. The singular somehow feels more formal to me, though I’m not sure why. I think of singular/plural as similar to how it works with possessives: “He broke John, Michael, and Jenny’s nose(s)”, where the singular doesn’t indicate they have only one nose between them, and the plural doesn’t indicate they have several noses each. Where several one-to-one relationships are present, either number makes logical sense, at least, whether they’re both in practical use or not.

Comment: I parse it as "The first months... are March and June...".  In other words, I assign the agreements under the assumption that "of spring and summer" and "respectively" can be elided.

Answer (score 1):

The form illustrated is fairly well established in scientific and mathematical writing.  While it usually is understandable it often is distracting and unclear.  Frequently, rewriting the sentence to state the alternative elliptically is better.  For example:

> The first month of Spring is March; of Summer, June.
>   *or*
>    The first month of Spring is March, and that of Summer is June.
>   *rather than*
>   The first month of Spring (respectively Summer) is March (respectively June).

Note that in this case, the forms shown are shorter and smoother than the original.

Here is an example (from a [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22respectively%20left%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl) search showing many such) that illustrates the form as often used in academic papers:

> In the search to the right (respectively, left), we determine the subset containing R(Ui) (respectively, L(Ui)) as follows. Mark a block full (respectively, partial) if all (respectively, part) of its endpoints are marked. – *Graph-Theoretic Concepts in Computer Science: 18th International Workshop*, ed. Ernst Mayr, 1993, [page 15 (Wen-Lian Hsu)](http://books.google.com/books?id=yu7fHH38BesC&pg=PA15&dq=%22respectively+left%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GdSFVL-KB4XmoAS12YGwBA&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22respectively%20left%22&f=false)

Comment: That Google Books search does show that most of the people who use this expression (Ernst Mayr included) are not native English speakers. There is a suspiciously high ratio of German-sounding names in particular. I do believe you that the construction has become quite common in certain technical fields; but I doubt it entered these fields through use by native speakers originally.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, I noticed a high percentage of non-Anglo names. I'm unwilling to conclude from that that most people using this expression are not native English speakers or that it entered the English language in that way.  For one thing, many of the writers may have had native-English-speaker advisors.  For another, I've seen the form used by many British and American authors.  (I don't approve of the form, so it sticks out memorably when I do see it.)  Note, Ernst Mayr edited the referenced volume; Wen-Lian Hsu was author of paper.

Comment: @jwpat7 Indeed this question was motivated by the examples I have seen in scientific literature. Evidently this expression is considered acceptable by the editors of these publications, nevertheless, I agree that this does not imply correctness. A fair comment would be that this use of respectively is a convention used in the sciences introduced by the high proportion of non-native English speakers in the field.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, you can rewrite the sentence without distorting the meaning as;

The first months of the Spring and Summer are March and June respectively